# Can lapply and sapply functions be used on a matrix or data frame with different base functions of R?

Tags: r

trying to use `lapply` or `sapply` on a given mattrix using function rowSums.

Given mattrix;

```r
mat <- matrix(1:9, ncol = 3, nrow = 3)
```

when I use `lapply(mat, rowSums)`, it should calculate sum of all rows.

However its showing error

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
> 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
> Calls: sapply -> lapply -> FUN
> Execution halted

Where am I doing wrong, Please help.

Comment: You can use `rowSums(mat)`.

Comment: thanks, but I am new to R programming and trying to understand the use and application of apply functions family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a matrix you can use `apply`:

```
apply(mat, 1, sum)
```

Parameter `1` indicates that you are performing the `sum` function on the rows (`2` for the columns)

Comment: thanks, but does it mean that lapply and sapply functions cannot use matix or dataframe as input?

Comment: `lapply` and `sapply` take either a vector or a list as input, but not a matrix or dataframe. You can use a dataframe inside the function to be executed, but not as an input; for example, suppose to have a dataframe `df` with 5 column `lapply (1:5, function (x) df[[i])`

Comment: thanks, can you please tell me how apply family functions are helpful than loops. I am not able to understand this thing..

Comment: Unfortunately the question you ask does not have an answer of a few lines. I advise you to practice slowly, trying from time to time a problem to which to apply the functions of the `apply` family. To practice, first use `for` loops and then try to replace them with functions from the `apply` (or `tidyverse`) family. I leave you an excellent starting point:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family